# SAS logic to generate values for another variable

Tags: sas, sas-macro

| Subject | REGNO | derived | Date of Mets | FDDAT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001-003 | 1 |  | 2/15/2018 | 2-Sep-14 |
| 001-003 | 1 |  | 2/15/2018 | 14-Oct-14 |
| 001-003 | 1 |  | 2/15/2018 | 2-Sep-14 |
| 001-003 | 2 |  | 2/15/2018 | 8-Jun-15 |
| 001-003 | 3 | 1 | 2/15/2018 | 7-Mar-18 |
| 001-003 | 3 | 1 | 2/15/2018 | 7-Mar-18 |
| 001-003 | 4 | 2 | 2/15/2018 | 3-May-18 |
| 001-003 | 5 | 3 | 2/15/2018 | 25-Jun-18 |
| 001-003 | 5 | 3 | 2/15/2018 | 25-Jun-18 |

Hello,
I want to derive the derived variable using sas code.
iF FDDAT is before dateofmets then derived is blank.
iF FDDAT is after dateofmets then derived is,
for a given id, if regno match, then add 1 to the derived column.
if regno change then increment by 1, if regno same as above repeat the number.

Answer (score 0):

Use by-group processing and a sum statement to achieve this. SAS makes this very easy to do. We'll increment `derived` if the combination of `id, regno` differs. We can use `first.regno` to do this. `first.regno` automatically implies this combination. `first.regno` means it's the first within a group of `id, regno`. When this happens, we know that `regno` has changed within the group.

```
data want;
    set have;
    by id regno;

    /* Reset for the start of each id group */
    if(first.id) then derived = 0;

    /* Increment if (id, regno) changes */
    if(first.regno) then derived+1;
run;
```

```
  id    regno   derived
1234        3         1
1234        3         1
1234        4         2
1234        5         3
1235        1         1 
1235        1         1
1236        5         1
1236        6         2
```

Comment: Thank you for you reply. I have made some changes to the base table. Can you edit your code?

Answer (score 0):

The case of `regno` values being the same in adjacent rows but not necessarily sorted within `id` is called *contiguous*.  Data that are contiguous but disordered can be processed by adding the `BY` option `NOTSORTED`

Example:

```
data want;
  set have;
  by id regno NOTSORTED;

  if first.id then regno_group=1;
  else
  if first.regno then regno_group+1;
run;
```

The syntax *<var>+<expression>* is called a `SUM` **statement** and implicitly retains the *<var>* value over the DATA Step implicit loop.

For the updated question, the initialization of `regno_group` and its incrementation is more complex.

```
...
  if first.id then
    call missing(regno_group);

  if missing(regno_group) and fddat >= dateofmets then
    regno_group + 1;
  else
  if not missing(regno_group) then
    regno_group + (first.regno);
...
```

Comment: I made some changes to the base table. Can you please help me with it. 
Thank you in advance